# php app update: Invalid character in filename

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Problem when uploading php application which uses `Wordpress`

```
* version - 1.8.0
* language - php
* operating system - Windows 7
```

Update to the `GAE` shows the below error for many files. Tried renaming few files but the error pops for another file and so on. These are `wordpress 3.5.1` files.

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Invalid character in filename: __static__\wordpress/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css
--- end server output ---
```

The `app.yaml` content:

```
-------------------------------------------
application: fargocricketclub
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Comment: Could it be the back slash in static\wordpress/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css

Comment: no doubt it is - why don't you post your entire app.yaml file?

Comment: Hey guys- I edited the question adding the app.yaml content now. Thanks.

Comment: @StuartLangley I think the below is causing the backslash. Please propose a solution.                                                                                >>> import os; os.path.join('__static__','wordpress/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css')
'__static__\\wordpress/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css'

Comment: @StuartLangley I don't think I am doing it right but I replaced os.path.join with posixpath.join in google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py and upload went successful. There must be a right way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is fixed in the 1.8.1 release of App Engine, using the solution proposed above to join the path using the OS specific path separator.

Comment: Thanks for updating on this. It doesn't seem to be fixed though. Perhaps I am missing something. I did check the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seen in PHP & Python 1.8.1 deployments on Windows when using application_readable. Issue flagged: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9558

Work around:

replaced os.path.join with posixpath.join in google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py