# "Invalid character in filename: __static__" when deploying to Google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I get the same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822630/php-app-update-invalid-character-in-filename) with my Python app. Using appengine 1.8.1, when I try to deploy, I get the following error:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Invalid character in filename: __static__\static/config/sboxwsdl.xml
```

I guess it's complaining about the backslash. The part of the path "`__static__\`" is not something I can change in the application; it's done in the appengine code. Replacing os.path.join with posixpath.join in google/appengine/appcfg.py does not fix it. Here's my app.yaml file:

```
application: theappiamwriting
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /files/csv
  static_dir: static/csv
  mime_type: text/csv
  application_readable: true

- url: /files/config
  static_dir: static/config
  mime_type: text/xml
  application_readable: true
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the *code*; we cannot determine where the `\s` comes from here.

Comment: Edited the question to explain that the "\" is added by appengine code, not mine.

Comment: How about you show us your code *anyway*.

Comment: Check you don't have some sort of unicode character in "static" directory name.  Are you running on windows ?

Comment: All characters in the file and directory names are 7 bit ASCII chars. I am on Windows and all of the folders are inside my Google Drive folder. That's the only "special" thing I can think of.

Comment: Try it without google drive. My bet is google drive doesn't present full file system semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seen in PHP & Python 1.8.1 deployments on Windows when using application_readable.  Issue flagged:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9558

Work around:

replaced os.path.join with posixpath.join in Google Appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py

Comment: thanks for tip. That hasn't worked for me. In the meantime, the workaround I have is to define the content of each static file as a python variable and implement a handler that returns the contents. OK for my few text files, probably more of a hassle for binary files (which I don't have to worry about). Other option I thought of is hosting them in a separate appengine project (or of course somewhere else entirely). Appengine project should work, because from what I have read, the problem seems to be related to when you set the application_readable property to true.

Answer (score 0):

From the googleappengine issue mentioned above, the problem seems to arise when a static_dir is marked with application_readable=true under windows only.

A workaround, as this worked for me, is either to remove the application_readable attribute or move the files that need to be read by scripts to a separate directory without application_readable applied to it. (Remember that application_readable means files readable by scripts).

I tried replacing os.path.join with posixpath.join in appcfg.py, but it does not seem to work for version 1.8.1 of google app engine sdk.